# How do we evaluate this Definite Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck at this definite integral
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^k (1-x)^n}{(1-x)^k}\ dx.
$$

I tried using property of definite integral and substituted $x$ with $1-x$ but I am not going any further with this , Someone please help me out

Comment: why don't you simplify into $(1-x)^{n-k}$ ?

Comment: You could also use the binomial theorem to write out $(1-x)^{n-k}$ as a sum and then integrate eauch summand seperately.

Comment: @infinite_monkey will I get a simplified expression using it ?

Comment: Beta.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not reduce to
$$
\int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n dx
$$
and take it by parts, differentiating $(1-x)^n$ until it disappears?

E.g. if $u = (1-x)^n$ and $dv = x^m dx$ then $du = -n(1-x)^{n-1}dx$ and $v = \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}$ so $uv|_0^1 = 0$ and
$$
\begin{split}
I(m,n)
 &= \int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n dx \\
 &= \frac{n}{m+1} \int_0^1 x^{m+1} (1-x)^{n-1} dx \\
 &= \frac{n}{m+1} I(m+1,n-1)
\end{split}
$$
and now just solve the recurrence:
$$
\begin{split}
I(m,n)
 &= \frac{n}{m+1} I(m+1,n-1) \\
 &= \frac{n}{m+1} \frac{n-1}{m+2} I(m+2,n-2) \\
 &= \ldots \\
 &= \frac{n!m!}{(m+n)!} I(m+n,0) \\
 &= \frac{1}{\binom{m+n}{m}} \frac{1}{m+n+1}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: You don't need to do that: these integrals are well known under the name of [**Beta integrals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) $B(m+1,n+1)$ and can be expressed with $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

notice that:
$$I(n,k)=\int_0^1\frac{x^k(1-x)^n}{(1-x)^k}dx=\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx$$
and we have a definition for the beta function as follows:
$$B(a,b)=\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
and so:
$$I(n,k)=B(k+1,n-k+1)=\frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)}$$
which works for non-integer values too :)